# XML SAX creating an attribute out of content

Tags: xml, attributes, sax

I have a large XML file of which I need to transform one particular element.

Its text content should become an attribute.

```
<myelement>textContent</myelement>
```

to

```
<myelement newAttribute="textContent">textContent</myElement>
```

There is more to it, but the above represents the crystallized problem of mine.

I am using Perl and SAX filters to get to the place I am now and I will need to use Perl and SAX after that again, as DOM is not possible for some of the stuff I do and as the overall file is massive.

My question is - can the above transformation be done in Perl & Sax too - and if so, how?

The code I have so far - but it produces awesome rubbish is

```
package addContentToAttributes;


use base qw(XML::SAX::Base);
my $inReference = 0;
my $referenceContent = "";

sub start_element {
my ($self, $element) = @_;

} 
if (($element->{Name} eq "myelement"){
 $inMyElement = 1;
 $myElementContent = "";
} 
else {
    $self->SUPER::start_element($element);
}
}

sub characters{
    my($self,$element) = @_;

if ($inmyElement) {
        $myElementContent = $myElementContent.$element->{Data};
    }
else {
$self->SUPER::characters($element)
}
;
}  

sub end_element {
my ($self, $element) = @_;

if (($element->{Name} eq "myElement")  {

    my $newNode = {  };
        %$newNode = %$self;

        $newNode->{Name} = 'myElement';     
    $ref_node->{Attributes}{'{}newAttribute'} = { Name =>"newAttribute", Value=>$myElementContent};
        $self->SUPER::start_element($newNode);
        $self->SUPER::characters({Data => $myElementContent});
        $self->SUPER::end_element($newNode);    

}
else {
     $self->SUPER::end_element($element)};
    }  

1;
```

Comment: This can be done. Where is the code that you have so far?

Comment: I have added above the code I have so far. It is a (massive) abbreviation of my actual code, as the problem I want to fix is a lot bigger - but this is only place where I struggle.

Comment: You think you can make it so that the code actually runs (currently there are syntax errors) and reproduces the problem you see (i.e. complete with sample input and output)?